# Compare fields of two files

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have two files like this:

File 1

```
apple fruit 10 4
strawberry fruit 22 11
berry fruit 33 33
ball toy 1 12
straw thing 2 33
```

File 2

```
strawberry straw berry
rawberry raw berry
```

I want to compare column 1 of file 2 with column 1 of file 1, column 2 of file 2 with column 1 of file 1, column 3 of file 2 with column 1 of file 1. If match is found, I want to display all three matching lines from file 1.

Here, the output should be:

```
strawberry fruit 22 11
straw thing 2 33
berry fruit 33 33
```

How can I do this using Unix commands on terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Based in Arijit Chatterjee proposal, I sugest

```
grep -Ff <(tr -s " " "\n" < file2) file1
```

Where `tr -s " " "\n"` transforms file2 in a one-word-per-line input, better 
adapted for `grep -Ff`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `grep -Ff File2 File1`

Where, the -f File2 reads the patterns from File2 and the -F treats the patterns as fixed strings

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, you could put all of the words of `File2` into an associative array and then check field 1 of `File2` for membership:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++; next} $1 in a' File2 File1
strawberry fruit 22 11
berry fruit 33 33
straw thing 2 33
```

A similar solution could be implemented using a hash in `perl`